# Why is Audio not Audible when i download using pytube in kivy application?

Tags: python, kivy, pytube

I am working on a kivy based application Which can download youtube videos using the pytube Api
I am able to download the videos in all resolutions using pytube only But when I Put this logic into the Kivy application I am able to download only 360p with both video and audio.
If I change to any other resolution it gets downloaded but there is no audio.
Please Help me How to solve the problem

My code only with Pytube

```
from pytube import YouTube

url = input('Enter the link to Link download')
type1 = int(input('1.Video\n2.Audio'))
mime_type = ''
if type1 == 1:
    mime_type = 'video'
elif type1 == 2:
    mime_type = 'audio'
else:
    print('Please select appropriatly')
    exit()

type2 = int(input('1.mp4\n2.webm'))

if type2 == 1:
    mime_type += '/mp4'
elif type2 == 2:
    mime_type += '/webm'
else:
    print('Please select appropriatly')
    exit()

name = input('Name Of the file? : ')

try:
    yt = YouTube(url)
except:
    print('Couldnt connect')
    exit()

if type1 == 2:
    stream = yt.streams.filter(mime_type=mime_type).first()
    stream.download(filename=name)
    print("Download successfull")
    exit()


def resolution():
    res_query = int(input('Select Resolution\n1.144p\n2.240p\n3.360p\n4.480p\n5.720p\n6.1080p'))
    res = ''
    if res_query == 1:
        res = '144p'
    elif res_query == 2:
        res = '240p'

    elif res_query == 3:
        res = '360p'
    elif res_query == 4:
        res = '480p'

    elif res_query == 5:
        res = '720p'

    elif res_query == 6:
        res = '1080p'
    else:
        print('Enter appropriate resolution')
        exit()


res = resolution()
stream = yt.streams.filter(mime_type=mime_type, res=res)
if stream == []:
    print('Resolution of {} is not availible for download\nPlease try with different resolution')
    res = resolution()

else:
    stream.first().download(filename=name)
    print("Download successfull")
```

My Youtube downloader using kivy Gui

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from pytube import YouTube

class Option(Screen):

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        Window.clearcolor = (0.15, 0.15, 1, 1)


class Video(Screen):
    url = ObjectProperty(None)
    res=ObjectProperty(None)
    filename = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

    def Download(self):
        print(self.url.text)
        print(self.res.text)
        mime_type = 'video/mp4'

        yt=YouTube(self.url.text)
        stream = yt.streams.filter(mime_type=mime_type, res=self.res.text).first()
        stream.download(filename=self.filename.text)
        print('Download Done')




class Audio(Screen):
    url = ObjectProperty(None)
    filename=ObjectProperty(None)



    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)



    def Download(self):
        print(self.url.text)

        mime_type = 'audio/mp4'
        yt = YouTube(self.url.text)
        stream = yt.streams.filter(mime_type=mime_type).first()
        stream.download(filename=self.filename.text)


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
kv = Builder.load_file('You.kv')


class YouApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (360, 600)
        self.icon = r'icon.png'
        sm.add_widget(Option())
        sm.add_widget(Video())
        sm.add_widget(Audio())
        return sm


YouApp().run()
```

My kv file

```
<Manager>:
    Option:
        id:option
        name:'option'
    Audio:
        id:audio
        name:'audio'
    Video:
        id:video
        name:'video'

<Option>
    name:'option'


    Widget:
        size_hint:[0.3,0.2]
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'top':0.92}

        canvas:
            Ellipse:
                size:self.size
                pos:self.pos
                source:'icon.png'


    GridLayout:
        rows:2
        size_hint:[0.8,0.27]
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}


        Button:
            text:" Download Video"
            background_color:204/255,229/255,1,1
            on_press:
                app.root.transition.direction='left'
                app.root.current='video'

        Button:
            text:"Download Audio"
            background_color:204/255,229/255,1,1
            on_press:
                app.root.transition.direction='right'
                app.root.current='audio'



<Video>
    name:'video'
    res:res
    url:url
    filename:filename
    Widget:
        size_hint:[0.3,0.2]
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'top':0.92}

        canvas:
            Ellipse:
                size:self.size
                pos:self.pos
                source:'icon.png'
    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        spacing:15
        size_hint:[0.8,0.25]
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'top':0.6}

        Label:
            text:'Url : '
            color:0,0,0,1

        TextInput:
            id :url
            multiline :False
            font_size:20

        Label:
            text:'Resolution : '
            color:0,0,0,1

        TextInput:
            id :res
            text:'360p'
            multiline :False
            font_size:20

        Label:
            text:'Video Name '
            color:0,0,0,1

        TextInput:
            id :filename
            multiline :False
            font_size:20




    Button:
        text:'Download'
        size_hint:[0.8,0.1]
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'top':0.3}
        on_press:root.Download()

    Button:
        text:'Back'
        size_hint:[0.8,0.1]
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'top':0.18}
        on_press:app.root.current='option'

<Audio>
    name:'audio'
    url:url
    filename:filename


    Widget:
        size_hint:[0.3,0.2]
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'top':0.92}

        canvas:
            Ellipse:
                size:self.size
                pos:self.pos
                source:'icon.png'
    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        spacing:15
        size_hint:[0.8,0.2]
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'top':0.6}

        Label:
            text:'Url : '
            color:0,0,0,1

        TextInput:
            id :url
            multiline :False
            font_size:20

        Label:
            text:'Audio Name '
            color:0,0,0,1

        TextInput:
            id :filename
            multiline :False
            font_size:20




    Button:
        text:'Download'
        size_hint:[0.8,0.1]
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'top':0.35}
        on_press:root.Download()

    Button:
        text:'Back'
        size_hint:[0.8,0.1]
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'top':0.18}
        on_press:app.root.current='option'
```

I am not Understanding where i am going wrong
Please help.
ThankYou

Answer (score 0):

Since the video file is downloaded successfully, you can download the audio file associated with the video then combine both of them using `ffmpeg`

**Step 1**

Install `ffmpeg` through this command:

`pip install ffmpeg-python`

**Step 2**

Download the audio file using:

`yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(save_path, f"{title}.mp3")`

where `yt` is a `Youtube` object.

**Step 3**

Combine video and audio files.

```
video_file = ffmpeg.input(join(save_path, f"{title}.mp4"))
audio_file = ffmpeg.input(join(save_path, f"{title}.mp3"))
ffmpeg.concat(video_file, audio_file, v=1, a=1).output(
        os.path.join(save_path, f"{title} .mp4")  #notice the space at the title here because we will delete the original file later
        ).run()
```

The original audio and video files are no longer needed. So, you can just delete them.

```
os.remove(os.path.join(save_path, f"{title}.mp4"))
os.remove(os.path.join(save_path, f"{title}.mp3"))
```

This will help you download even higher resolutions like 1080 and even 4k.